# Detect app state in iOS when occurring incoming call or any events on top of the app?

Tags: ios, react-native, background-task

**AppState** is not notifying in iOS when any activity comes on top of app.

> inactive - This is a state that occurs when transitioning between foreground & background, and during periods of inactivity such as entering the Multitasking view or in the event of an incoming call.

How to handle app when any events comes on top of an app like the incoming call events?

Comment: Did you try AppDelegate's `func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)`?

Comment: There is nothing called **activity** in iOS. You seem to be coming from android background. In short, we call such thing **events**. The state or change in state of your app is an event. You might want to go through [UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate?language=objc)

Comment: @nayem Looking into React Native Platform. Its actually detects in android. But there is no event detects in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below method to determine application status.

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }
```